# CodeIgnite Not Loading Default or any other Controllers on locahost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

The default controller (the welcome page) is not loading nor any other controllers. I have made no additional changes apart from what is listed below:

Downloaded and installed CI version 2.1.4 on WAMP to this directory -> 
`http://localhost/ci/` and after I set the config file element bellow:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

And after that I set the .htaccess from `Deny all` to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The 'directory' you are referring to is a *url*.

Comment: @brett-santore I tried `$config['base_url'] = '/ci/';` and still nothing.

Comment: Is WAMP working correctly? Can you display a hello world page using `echo 'hello';` on an index.php page on the root of your WAMP install.

Comment: @brett-santone Yes, I have multiple sites running on wamp within their separate folders. I even have another CI application of an older version (bambooInvoice) running without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the efforts in helping me set up CodeIgniter version 2.1.4. It seems that the package I original downloaded was faulty. After deleting the directory and downloading the CI files again, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need to set your base url:**

```
$config['base_url'] = ' ';


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt|favicon.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried that at first. Does not work. Same thing, loading default index page (//localhost/ci/index.php)

Comment: that will load `welcome_message.php` page which is view for `welcome` controller try to change its contents if you see the result, then there is nothing wrong, welcome_message file path is `ci/application/views/welcome_message.php`.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. But the issue is not with the .htaccess. If type `http://localhost/ci/index.php/welcome/index` that Model is not loaded, nor is the Welcome() controller. The default index.php in `http://localhost/ci/` is the one that shows. I've even tried changing from AUTO to REQUEST_URI. Still nothing. Thanks

Comment: what that default page says? can you paste the first line you see here?

Comment: `Directory access is forbidden.` This is the content of the default index.html page renamed to index.html.